# Why is my config file not used in single file project?

Tags: c#, .net-core, config

I have a .NET Core Console App file that uses .config file.

These is "Copy if needed" option selected in .config properties and ExcludeFromSingleFile=true code added to the project:

[image]

After I publish the project as self-contained single file, I see .exe, .pdb and two .config files:

[image]

As far as I understand the config file is not visible for the program. When I check a variable value, it shows an empty string. It kind of makes sense, since I am excluding the config file from a single file, although is there a way to have a single .exe file with a valid .config file?

If I publish the program without "single file" option checked, everything is working correctly.

Comment: Just to make sure. After you compile the config values are supposed to be in the myApp.dll.config. Are those also the same?

Comment: How are you loading/reading from the config file in your code? Also, .NET Core generally uses appsettings.json files for configuration instead of App.config: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration#configure-console-apps

Comment: @Fred Yes, the values are the same, although when I change them, the change is not visible to the program.

Comment: @devNull Do I understand it correctly that appsettings.json is used for ASP projects only? I have troubles getting how to add it to my Console App.

Comment: @Fred I have just realized that the config values are not visible at all when publishing as a single file (please see an updated problem description). Do you have any thoughts? And thank you for your first comment, it helped me to understand the situation.

Comment: @MishaKochubei I'm sorry I can't think of anything at the moment. If I do I'll get back to you.